# How to SORT with Null and YEAR?

Tags: sqlite, case, sql-order-by, sql-null

i want to sort with SQLITE so my data will show like this:

1. First sort by year asc, then alphabetic
2. If year is null then alphabetic desc

My ideas was :

```
ORDER by CASE WHEN year = NULL then Name Else year, name

ORDER by YEAR NULLS LAST
   , IIF(year != NULL, name, name desc) ;
```

But it does not work. I got an error. Do you have some ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always compare to `NULL` with the operator `IS` and never with `=`.

SQLite supports the `NULLS LAST/FIRST` clause since version 3.30.0.
If your version supports it then you can use:

```
ORDER BY year NULLS LAST,
         CASE WHEN year IS NOT NULL THEN name END,
         CASE WHEN year IS NULL THEN name END DESC;
```

If you use an older version you can use a boolean expression:

```
ORDER BY year IS NULL,
         year,
         CASE WHEN year IS NOT NULL THEN name END,
         CASE WHEN year IS NULL THEN name END DESC;
```

or a `CASE` expression:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN year IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
         year,
         CASE WHEN year IS NOT NULL THEN name END,
         CASE WHEN year IS NULL THEN name END DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SuF060xj).

Comment: Thanks but the NULL rows should order by name DESC

Comment: @Mikkey200 see my edited answer.

Comment: Look wonderfull